# How to optimize an increment query in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

in a Laravel project I am incrementing views based on session I am using it like this:

```php
$post = Post::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();

$postKey = 'post_'.$post->id;

if (!Session::has($postKey)) {
    $post->increment('views');
    Session::put($postKey, 1);
}
```

Is there any way to optimize this? I have activated the slow queries log and I am getting results like this one:

```
# Time: 2021-04-03T12:05:20.992056Z
# User@Host: user[user] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id: 168408
# Query_time: 2.843047  Lock_time: 0.000029 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1;
update `posts` set `views` = `views` + 1, `posts`.`updated_at` = '2021-04-03 12:05:18' where `id` = 163518;
```

How to optimize this? Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Adding a manual `EXPLAIN update` statement:

```
EXPLAIN update `posts` set `views` = `views` + 1, `posts`.`updated_at` = '2021-04-03 12:05:18' where `id` = 163518;
```

Result: 1 row in set (0.01 sec)

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UPDATE | posts | NULL | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more about your posts table. Can you run the query manually and prepend it with `EXPLAIN UPDATE `posts` ...` and show the result? See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: @dbrumann Yes, I will update it.

Comment: which query is the slow part? the update query looks fine, I suspect whereSlug(() to be slow. You may try to create an index on slug field.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond thanks, I missed setting an index on the slug, I will add it now and see how it holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use `ENGINE=MyISAM`; switch to InnoDB.
- Beware of other queries (in other connections) that are touching this table for a long time.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, in my database config file the mysql engine was NULL, I can set it up as `InnoDB`, if its NULL by default is it set to `MyISAM` by default?

Comment: @DarkBoss - Where are you seeing the `NULL`?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default_storage_engine';` will tell you what the default is.

Comment: And then it depends on what version of MySQL/MariaDB you are using.  Old versions defaulted to MyISAM; newer versions default to InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

That query is already as optimized as it can be.

There are no joins involved. The filtering (using where) is done by a primary key, `rows` = 1 and `filtered` = 100 means the query expects to visit [1] rows and return [100]% of them.

Maybe the table was locked at the time the query was executed.

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean the table was locked? Sorry if I don't understand you completely, this is my first tie trying to optimize performance, so it is pretty new to me.

Comment: If another query was modifying the table before this one, the database locks the table until that query is done to avoid conflicting data later on.

Comment: @DarkBoss - MyISAM locks the _entire_ table on any _write_.  InnoDB locks only the relevant _rows_, thereby allowing better "concurrency" when multiple connections are accessing the table.